# Automatic counter increment for bibliography statistics

Tags: bibliographies, excel, exceltex

I am trying to organize my bibliography in a tabular form, (with columns: year, Journal, topic...etc). The one thing I want to add, is to make a counter, so at the end, I will get automaticlly how many papers were written in every journal.

Latex, is the best for handeling bibliography, but automatic increment, I can only do that in Excel.

Can any one suggest something?

Comment: It's too late for the OP, but other future users may find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333182/101651) useful.