# Bibliography Entries in Separate Column of a Table

Tags: tables, biblatex, formatting

I want to display bibliography entries in separate columns of a table something like this one:

```
Authors      Year   Title           Journal        Vol. No.  Page No.  Note
A, B and C   2016   Article Title   Journal Name    1        10-15     ISI
```

MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\bibliography{BiblatexTableExample}

\begin{document}

To achieve incentive compatibility, the auction winner has to pay the second highest price \cite{Vickrey1961}.

A good introduction to graph algorithms can be found in \cite{Golumbic2004}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The contents of `BiblatexTableExample` are:

```
@ARTICLE{Vickrey1961,
AUTHOR = {W. Vickrey},
TITLE = {Counterspeculation, auctions and sealed tenders},
JOURNAL = {Journal of Finance},
YEAR = {1961},
volume = {16},
pages = {8--37},
} 

@BOOK{Golumbic2004,
AUTHOR = {M. C. Golumbic},
TITLE = {Algorithmic Graph Theory and Perfect Graphs},
PUBLISHER = {Elsevier Science},
YEAR = {2004},
edition = {2nd Edition},
}
```

Any help to accomplish this task will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest a solution with my favorite command: `\makecell`.

Obviously you may vary the column widths according to your taste, use the commented `\showframe` and `\frame` to see if you are going out of the page borders.

Of course, if you have bib entry types other than `book` and `article`, you have to build the corresponding `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`.

I've put the column headers on every page of the bibliography using `\AddThispageHook`. Since the hooks, once stacked, are unstackable, in case the bibliography is NOT the last thing of your document, it is necessary to include a conditional in the hook, in order to make it active only for bibliography pages.

```
\begin{filecontents}{BiblatexTableExample.bib}

    @ARTICLE{Vickrey1961,
        AUTHOR = {W. Vickrey},
        TITLE = {Counterspeculation, auctions and sealed tenders},
        JOURNAL = {Journal of Finance},
        YEAR = {1961},
        volume = {16},
        pages = {8--37},
        note = {a1b2c3}
    } 

    @BOOK{Golumbic2004,
        AUTHOR = {M. C. Golumbic},
        TITLE = {Algorithmic Graph Theory and Perfect Graphs},
        PUBLISHER = {Elsevier Science},
        YEAR = {2004},
        edition = {2nd Edition},
        note={ABC}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{showframe} % only for test purpose 
\usepackage{atbegshi}   
\usepackage{everypage}

% new commands to avoid repeating widths
\newcommand{\mysep}{\hspace{.01\textwidth}}
\newcommand{\myauthorprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.15\textwidth}}]{#1}}%
\newcommand{\myyearprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.07\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mytitleprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.26\textwidth}}]{#1}}%    
\newcommand{\myjournalprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.23\textwidth}}]{#1}}%    
\newcommand{\myvolprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.06\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mypageprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.07\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mynoteprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.10\textwidth}}]{#1}}%
\newcommand{\mybibheader}{
    \myauthorprint{Authors}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{Year}% 
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{Title}%    
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{Journal}%    
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{Vol. No.}% 
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{Page No.}% 
    \mysep
    \mynoteprint{Note}%
}   

% bib items separation
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}% plus 1pt minus 1pt} 

% remove dot after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

% normal text title (no italics, no ")
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{title}{#1}

% remove dot after title
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}

% publisher in italics
\DeclareListFormat[book]{publisher}{\textit{#1}}

% journaltitle in italics
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textit{#1}}

% remove dot after volume
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}

% remove pp.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1} 

% remove dot at the end of the bib entry
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \myauthorprint{\small\raggedright \printnames{author}}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{year}}%
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{title}}%
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{\small\raggedright \printlist{publisher}}%
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{\addspace}%
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{\addspace}%
    \mysep
    \mynoteprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{note}}%
    \finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \myauthorprint{\small\raggedright \printnames{author}}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{year}}%
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{title}}%
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{journaltitle}}%
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{volume}}%
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{pages}}%
    \mysep
    %\frame{% only for test purpose
    \mynoteprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{note}}%}%
    \finentry}

\addbibresource{BiblatexTableExample.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} % only for test purpose

\begin{document}

    To achieve incentive compatibility, the auction winner has to pay the second highest price \cite{Vickrey1961}.

    A good introduction to graph algorithms can be found in \cite{Golumbic2004}.

    Only for test purpose: \cite{knuth:ct} \cite{angenendt} \cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
    \cite{aristotle:anima}
    \cite{coleridge}
    \cite{knuth:ct:d}
    \cite{yoon}
    \cite{gillies}
    \cite{baez/article}

    \defbibnote{myprenote}{\noindent\mybibheader}

    \AddThispageHook{\AtBeginShipout{\mybibheader}}

    \printbibliography[prenote=myprenote]

\end{document}
```

First page: 
[image]

Second page:
[image]

EDIT:

In a comment, the OP has requested vertical as well as horizontal rulers with first column of serial number.

This is the best I can do (but some expert is needed to do better):

```
    \begin{filecontents}{BiblatexTableExample.bib}

    @ARTICLE{Vickrey1961,
        AUTHOR = {W. Vickrey},
        TITLE = {Counterspeculation, auctions and sealed tenders},
        JOURNAL = {Journal of Finance},
        YEAR = {1961},
        volume = {16},
        pages = {8--37},
        note = {a1b2c3}
    } 

    @BOOK{Golumbic2004,
        AUTHOR = {M. C. Golumbic},
        TITLE = {Algorithmic Graph Theory and Perfect Graphs},
        PUBLISHER = {Elsevier Science},
        YEAR = {2004},
        edition = {2nd Edition},
        note={ABC}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{showframe} % only for test purpose 
\usepackage{atbegshi}   
\usepackage{everypage}

% new commands to avoid repeating widths
\newcommand{\mysep}{\hspace{.01\textwidth}}
\newcommand{\mythickrule}{\hrule height .7pt}
\newcommand{\mynumberprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.05\textwidth}}]{#1}}%
\newcommand{\myauthorprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.14\textwidth}}]{#1}}%
\newcommand{\myyearprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.07\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mytitleprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.23\textwidth}}]{#1}}%    
\newcommand{\myjournalprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.19\textwidth}}]{#1}}%    
\newcommand{\myvolprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.06\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mypageprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.07\textwidth}}]{#1}}% 
\newcommand{\mynoteprint}[1]{\makecell[t{p{.10\textwidth}}]{#1}}%
\newcommand{\mybibheader}{%
    \mythickrule 
    \vskip1.2\itemsep
    \mynumberprint{No.}%
    \hspace{.23cm}
    %\frame{% for testing purpose only 
    \myauthorprint{Authors}%}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{Year}%
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{Title}%    
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{Journal}%    
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{Vol. No.}% 
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{Page No.}% 
    \mysep
    \mynoteprint{Note}%
    \vskip\itemsep
    \mythickrule}   

% bib items separation
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}% 

% small serial number
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mynumberprint{\small \raggedleft #1.}}

% remove dot after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

% normal text title (no italics, no ")
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{title}{#1}

% remove dot after title
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}

% publisher in italics
\DeclareListFormat[book]{publisher}{\textit{#1}}

% journaltitle in italics
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textit{#1}}

% remove dot after volume
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}

% remove pp.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1} 

% remove dot at the end of the bib entry
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \myauthorprint{\small\raggedright \printnames{author}}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{year}}%
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{title}}%
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{\small\raggedright \printlist{publisher}}%
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{\addspace}%
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{\addspace}%
    \mysep
    \mynoteprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{note}}%
    \finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \myauthorprint{\small\raggedright \printnames{author}}%
    \mysep
    \myyearprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{year}}%
    \mysep
    \mytitleprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{title}}%
    \mysep
    \myjournalprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{journaltitle}}%
    \mysep
    \myvolprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{volume}}%
    \mysep
    \mypageprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{pages}}%
    \mysep
    %\frame{% only for test purpose
    \mynoteprint{\small\raggedright \printfield{note}}%}%
    \finentry}

\addbibresource{BiblatexTableExample.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} % only for test purpose

\begin{document}

    To achieve incentive compatibility, the auction winner has to pay the second highest price \cite{Vickrey1961}.

    A good introduction to graph algorithms can be found in \cite{Golumbic2004}.

    Only for test purpose: \cite{knuth:ct} \cite{angenendt} \cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
    \cite{aristotle:anima}
    \cite{coleridge}
    \cite{knuth:ct:d}
    \cite{yoon}
    \cite{gillies}
    \cite{baez/article}

    \defbibnote{myprenote}{\noindent\mybibheader}

    \AddThispageHook{\AtBeginShipout{\mybibheader}}
    \printbibliography[prenote=myprenote]
    \mythickrule

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX for nice answer. I would prefer Journal in italic. Other things look fine to me at first sight.

Comment: That is great @CarLaTeX. Would love to have vertical as well as horizontal rulers with first column of serial number. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've posted the solution with the headers at every pages of the bibliography. As for the rulers and the serial numbers, I'll try to add them but I don't know if I am able to do that. Two questions: 1. If there is no enough room to add the serial number column, is it ok to print the bibliography landscape instead of portrait? 2. Are you aware that LaTeX purists hate vertical rulers? :)

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've added a new version with serial number and horizontal rulers in the header. I tried to print also an horizontal ruler between the bib entries but in some cases the last rule of one page goes on the following page, so I removed them. I have also tried to add vertical rulers but without a good result. Maybe you should post another question if you need this formatting.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You are welcome! Unfortunalety I'm not an expert...