# Is there a easy way to put bibliography in a table?

Tags: tables, bibliographies

I would like to know if there exist a bibliography style or if there is a easy way to generate a bibliography that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Bibliographies like the one shown are certainly very rare (almost non-existent) in scholarly works. For starters, the table does not contain the usual minimal information for a bibliography (which would also include year and at least one of publisher and location; for `@article`s you would definitely the journal and volume etc.) Secondly, most bibliographies in TeX don't use tables, instead they use lists.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Start from this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332710/bibliography-entries-in-separate-column-of-a-table/333182#333182 and edit your post adding a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: My personal advice: don't do it. It is very ugly.

Comment: @Johannes_B and moewe: I don't like that kind of bibliography style either, but it is a requirement. Sincerely I would done it in another way too.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I didn't find any minimal working example while googling so I thought it makes no sense to add a working example of some other bibliography style that doesn't match at all that what I need. Instead I tried to put a graphic so that it will be clearer. Thank you all!

Comment: For the future: _you_  should create a MWEB, trying to do something, not copying it from the internet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s package `biblatex-ext-tabular` you can create tabular bibliographies like the ones in [tabular bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864), in fact the code is largely inspired by Audrey's work in that question. You will need at least version 0.5 of `biblatex-ext` and you can read more about tabular bibliographies in §6 *Tabular Bibliographies* of its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

For a simple three-column set-up with label, title and author you don't need a lot of code. But you should be aware of the fact that this information alone is not always enough to properly identify a work. `@collection`s don't have authors, they have editors. Even `@books` usually have more information in the bibliography than just the title and author: the year of publication is present in almost all styles and at least one of publisher or location is very common. `@article`s would generally need at least a `journal` and a publication date.  The situation is worse for other contained works like `@incollection` which may be next to impossible to find without knowing the enclosing work.

**Not only does this not look very pretty, it is almost certainly not enough information for a proper bibliography. – *Don't do this.***

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
                     @{}
                     C{\dimexpr0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                     @{}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Author}\\
     \midrule}
  {\bottomrule
   \end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printnames{author}} \\}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{worman,geer,nussbaum,companion}
\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular bibliography with label number, title and author.]

---

Compare this with the usual output of a numeric bibliography. If you want to put additional emphasis on the author name, you can make it bold.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{worman,geer,nussbaum,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Usual list bibliography with bold author names so they stand out more.]

Comment: thank you!! that's what I was looking for but unfortunately  I couldn't find any reference to that package while googling.

Comment: @pin_ftv It is still fairly new.