# Use custom field and count elements of lists in references using biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, database

I have a primary source and analyzed its references (on which pages are the references cited, like a manual `backref` job). I created a new library for this (like the author would to if he had LaTeX a few centuries ago) and added a custom field `citedonpages` with the manually discovered pages.

I would like to print this analyzed data (e.g. for displaying it in a table). Is it possible to use `biblatex/biber` to process additional fields (in this case `citedonpages` as described in `citedonpages.dbx`) to

- print this list for each entry
- and count the comma separated entries?

I tried to follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163396/4419 but the command `\printfield{citedonpages}` did non work.

How can I access (print) the `citedonpages` field and how can I count the entries of the comma-separated values? As the real library has many entries, an automated solution would be very helpful (and ideally completely within LaTeX).

[image: MWE preview]

MWE (as a follow-up question of [Create table from references with custom fields as columns using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/606362/4419)):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents*}{citedonpages.dbx}
    \ProvidesFile{citedonpages.dbx}[2021/07/27 add citedonpages field to biblatex data model]
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{citedonpages} %comma seperated list of values
    \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{citedonpages}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Analysis.bib}
@Book{Miller1832a,
    author    = {John Miller},
    title     = {Elementary book},
    year      = {1832},
    citedonpages = {67,68,97},
}

@InBook{Smith1744a,
    author    = {Daniel Smith},
    booktitle = {Collection of important articles},
    location  = {Amsterdam},
    title     = {Noteworthy Article},
    year      = {1744},  
    citedonpages = {5, 23, 37, 79, 248, 249, 254},
}
\end{filecontents*}
%\addbibresource{Analysis.bib}

\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,datamodel=citedonpages,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citedonpages}{\bibstring{citedonpages}\space #1}
    
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{##2}%
   \begin{longtable}{@{}llccl@{}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{\# Citations} & \dots\ on pages\\
     \midrule}
  {\bottomrule
   \end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printdate}
   & 0 % how to display counter
   & \printfield{citedonpages}
   \\}


\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[Analysis.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\textbf{Ideally, it should output something like:}\\
Miller, John. \textit{Elementary book}. 1832. (cited 3 times on pages 67, 68, 97)\\
Smith, Daniel. “Noteworthy Article”. In: \textit{Collection of important articles}. Amsterdam,
1744. (cited 7 times on pages 5, 23, 37, 79, 248, 249, 254)

\vspace{1cm}\textbf{Version with table} (added manually):

\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{llccX}
        \toprule 
        {\bfseries Author} & {\bfseries Title}  & {\bfseries Year} & {\bfseries \#  Citations}  & ... on pages \\\midrule%\otoprule 
                Miller, John       & Elementary book    & 1832             & 3 & 67, 68, 97\\
        Smith, Daniel      & "Noteworthy article" & 1744           & 7 & 5, 23, 37, 79, 248, 249, 254 \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}\textbf{Version with table} (autogenerated, but entries are missing):

\begin{refsection}[Analysis.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibtabular[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `expl3` code to read the list of pages, remove duplicate numbers and count the number of pages.

This can be done in `\DeclareFieldInputHandler`, so happens right when the field `citedonpages` is read from the `.bbl` file. From the on, `citedonpages` contains a nicely formatted list of pages (without duplication).

The remaining code can be taken almost verbose from [Create table from references with custom fields as columns using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/606362/35864), we just need to print our `citedonpages` field instead of the `biblatex` `pageref` list.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{citedonpages.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{citedonpages.dbx}[2021/07/27 add citedonpages field to biblatex data model]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{citedonpages}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{citedonpages}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, datamodel=citedonpages]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__kromuchiblx_citedonpages_clist

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{citedonpages}
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l__kromuchiblx_citedonpages_clist {#1}
    % remove duplicates, if you want the duplicates counted,
    % move this line *after* the citecount definition
    \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l__kromuchiblx_citedonpages_clist
    % writing a new field *while* we are processing another
    % is a bit risky, ...
    \blx@bbl@fieldedef{citecount}{\clist_count:N \l__kromuchiblx_citedonpages_clist}
    % ... but works if we make sure *we* write \NewValue
    \edef\NewValue{\clist_use:Nn \l__kromuchiblx_citedonpages_clist {,~}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{tablepageref}{%
  \printfield{citedonpages}}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{##2}%
   \renewbibmacro*{labeltitle}{}%
   \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{}%
   \setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
                     @{}
                     L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-1\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                     L{\dimexpr0.21\textwidth-1\tabcolsep\relax}
                     @{}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{\# Citations} & \dots\ on pages\\
     \midrule}
  {\bottomrule
   \end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printdate}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{citecount}} 
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{tablepageref}} \\}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Miller1832a,
  author       = {John Miller},
  title        = {Elementary book},
  year         = {1832},
  citedonpages = {67,67,68,97,67},
}
@inbook{Smith1744a,
  author       = {Daniel Smith},
  booktitle    = {Collection of important articles},
  location     = {Amsterdam},
  title        = {Noteworthy Article},
  year         = {1744},  
  citedonpages = {5, 23, 37, 79, 248, 249, 254},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibtabular[title=Analysis]
\end{document}
```

[image: Miller, John Elementary book 1832 3 67, 68, 97//Smith, Daniel ‘Noteworthy Article’ 1744 7 5, 23, 37, 79, 248, 249, 254]

Comment: This is like magic... Thank you very much. Would it be possible to sort the table by number of citations? Is it possible at all? And if so can it be extended to the existing structure or would it be better to open a new question?

Comment: @kromuchi That is trickier. Sorting is done by Biber. But Biber does not have the number of citations available (the `citedonpages` field is only parsed on the LaTeX side). For that it would be easier to generate the counting by the same software that generates the `citedonpages` data. If the number of citations is available as a field in its own right, Biber can sort by it.

Comment: @kromuchi FWIW `biblatex` v3.17/Biber 2.17 can now sort by number of citations. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1146.

Comment: How easy / hard would it be to replace consecutive pages `67, 68, 69` within the field `citedonpages` by a abbreviated (pageref-like) style `67--69`?

Comment: @kromuchi Integer/string operations like this are always a bit painful (though of course not impossible). But given that the number of citations is now available, maybe you can do away with `citedonpages` completely and just use the normal `backref` feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use backref here, because it is a different document. I am analyzing an old document (say from 1800) and its references. So I created a bib file with all the references from the 200 year old book (and there are many). That's why I need to use the citedonoages field and can't use backref. However, if there is no easy solution, I have to use something like python to do all the preprocessing and create the table.