# Detect last row in biblatex-ext-tabular / formatting rules

Tags: biblatex, longtable, biblatex-ext

I am using `biblatex-ext` and `longtable` for typesetting a bib-based references table. For a better overview, I want to seperate the individual rows with rules and print a bold rule at the bottom as well. Due to aesthetic reasons, I reformatted the reoccuring rules as well and made them thinner and grey.

Unfortuately, the row seperator rule is also printed after the last row, just before the extra bottom rule:

[image: current output result]

From the `biblatex-ext` manual, there is no obvious option to distinguis any rows (e.g. even/odd rows): `\defbibtabular{⟨name⟩}{⟨begin code⟩}{⟨end code⟩}{⟨row code⟩}`.

How can I either

- rearrange the whole rule-formatting code such that it fits into the `biblatex-ext-tabular` environment or
- detect whether the row is the last row in the table (and hence omit the rule output)
  to avoid the double line at the end of my table?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Year}\\
     \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]\endhead%
        \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%--prepare color for all midrules
        }
  {\arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
   \end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printdate}
     \\\midrule[0.3pt]}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Miller1832a,
  author       = {John Miller},
  title        = {Elementary book},
  year         = {1832},
}
@inbook{Smith1744a,
  author       = {Daniel Smith},
  booktitle    = {Collection of important articles},
  title        = {Noteworthy Article},
  year         = {1744},  
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

PS: This MWE is copied (and modified) from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609231/4419)

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable.

Comment: Sorry, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend the `defbibtabular` to `\defbibtabular{⟨name⟩}{⟨begin code⟩}{⟨end code⟩}{⟨row code⟩}{⟨between row code⟩}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dirty fix would be to add another last (and empty) row, but with negative row height such that the bold `bottomrule` line is just printed above the thin gray `midrule` line. It's not a nice solution, but it works:

[image]

Here the patched MWE (just must run it 2 or 3 times for the final result):

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Year}\\
     \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]\endhead%
        \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%--prepare color for all midrules
        }
  {\\[-0.6cm]\arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
   \end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printdate}
     \\\midrule[0.3pt]}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Miller1832a,
  author       = {John Miller},
  title        = {Elementary book},
  year         = {1832},
}
@inbook{Smith1744a,
  author       = {Daniel Smith},
  booktitle    = {Collection of important articles},
  title        = {Noteworthy Article},
  year         = {1744},  
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```